# How to convert words into a sentence?

Tags: delphi

I must ask the user to enter words (one at a time), until "xxx" is entered. I must then build a sentence with those words with one space between each word. The sentence must be displayed as soon as the terminating string ("xxx") is entered.

My code only displays "xxx", the terminating code.

Note: We haven't started with Arrays yet.

This is the code I tried so far:

```
unit BuildSentence_U;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  btnResult: TButton;
redOut: TRichEdit;
procedure btnResultClick(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private declarations }
public
  { Public declarations }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnResultClick(Sender: TObject);
Var wrd : string;
begin

wrd := inputbox('Word input', ' Enter any word to build a sentence     (press "xxx" to stop)','');
redOut.Clear;

while (wrd <> 'xxx') do
 begin
  wrd := wrd + ' ';
  wrd := inputbox('Word input', ' Enter any word to build a sentence (press"xxx" to stop)','');
 end;
redOut.Lines.Add(wrd);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another string to collect words together:

```
Var 
  wrd, sentence : string;
begin

wrd := inputbox('Word input', ' Enter any word to build a sentence     (press "xxx" to stop)','');
redOut.Clear;

while (wrd <> 'xxx') do
 begin
  sentence := sentence + wrd + ' ';
  wrd := inputbox('Word input', ' Enter any word to build a sentence (press"xxx" to stop)','');
 end;
redOut.Lines.Add(sentence);
```